# Collectibles with different score values

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, hittest

I have an array of randomly spawning collectibles. When they collide with the player, they are removed from the stage and the score increases by a scoreValue. I want each collectible in the array to have a different scoreValue, but I haven't been able to get it. Below is all of my most recent code pertaining to this.

```
public class Main_EnemySpawnTest_3 extends MovieClip
{
    // variables
    var player:Player = new Player;
    var collectables:Array = [Collectable1, Collectable2, Collectable3];
    var collectablesRandomNumber:int = Math.random() * (collectables.length);
    var collectable = new collectables[collectablesRandomNumber];
    var score:uint = 0;

    // constructor function
    public function Main_EnemySpawnTest_3():void
    {
        // listeners
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkEveryFrame);
        spawnCollectablesButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spawnCollectablesClick);
    }

    // enter frame, check every frame
    public function checkEveryFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        // score
        messageDisplay.text = String (score);
    }

    // hit test
    function hitTest (event:Event):void
    {
        // hit test with collectables
        if (collectable.hitTestObject (player) == true)
        {
            var scoreValue:uint;

            if (stage.contains (collectable))
            {
                if (collectables[0])
                {
                    scoreValue = 100;
                }
                else if (collectables[1])
                {
                    scoreValue = 300;
                }
                else if (collectables[2])
                {
                    scoreValue = 700;
                }
                removeChild (collectable);
                score = score + scoreValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, the collectables are being spawned with a button click. The code for that is below, if it helps.

```
// collectable spawn button
function spawnCollectablesClick (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var oldCollectable = collectable;
    if (stage.contains (oldCollectable))
    {
        removeChild (oldCollectable);
    }       
var collectablePositionRandomNumber:int = Math.random() * 3; 
    var collectablePositionX:int = stage.width - (collectable.width * -0.5);
    collectable = new collectables[Math.floor(Math.random() * collectables.length)];
    collectable.x = collectablePositionX;
    globalSpeed = 5;
    if (collectablePositionRandomNumber == 0)
    {
        collectable.y = topPosition;
    }
    else if (collectablePositionRandomNumber == 1)
    {
        collectable.y = centerPosition;
    }
    else if (collectablePositionRandomNumber == 2)
    {
        collectable.y = bottomPosition;
    }
    addChild (collectable);
    trace (collectable);
}
```

Comment: how do you create/instantiate your collectables?  Let me guess, your score always goes up by 100?   When you do `if(collectables[0])`, it's just looking for a truthy value.  So as long as the result of `collectables[0]` isn't null/false/undefined/negative number,  it will evaluate as true.  Since you have what is presumably an object in `collectables[0]`, the condition will always be true.

Comment: At the moment, I'm working on this code in its own the collectables are being spawned with a button click. Eventually, it will be a timer, tile-based array, or something else.
I'll put the code in the original post

Comment: Collectable1, 2, and 3 are from the collectables array. Each is its own collectable item (right now, different colored and shaped coins). I need them to award different score values when they collide with the player. Right now the code runs but it always only awards 100 points. I need each coin collision to give its correct point value, so 100 for Collectable1, 300 for Collectable2, and 700 for Collectable3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from `if (collectables[0])`:  This will return true as long as `collectables[0]` isn't `false`/`null`/`0`/`NaN` or `undefined`. So you're always going to be adding 100 and the `else if`s will always be skipped.

You can give the collectable its own score value when creating it in `spawnCollectablesClick`:

```
collectable.scoreValue = ...
```

Then use that to increment the score

```
function hitTest (event:Event):void
{
    // hit test with collectables
    if (collectable.hitTestObject (player) == true)
    {
        score = score + collectable.scoreValue;
        removeChild (collectable);
    }
}
```

As a side note, if `Collectible1`, `Collectible2`, and `Collectible3` are all different classes, you're defeating the purpose of classes.  If 3 things have the same behavior but different values for things, they can all be instances of the same class with different member variable values.

Comment: I've only been programming for a few months, so I'm not sure how to do what you're suggesting. I've had the code exactly how you wrote it out before, but it doesn't solve the problem. Also, I'm only using a single class. I've had no luck with multiple classes, and even if I can get them to work, they are just a huge hassle and make coding more difficult and messy rather than less so.